# login postgres with a freshly created user

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a new user

```
postgres-# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 prac      | Superuser
```

However, when tried to login with the account

It report error:

```
$ psql --user prac
Password for user prac: 
psql: FATAL:  database "prac" does not exist
```

The error `psql: FATAL:  database "prac" does not exist`?

It first recognize `prac` as a user, then report it not a database?

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL by default tries to connect to the database with the same name as the user.

So explicitly specify the database you want:

```sh
psql --user=prac --dbname=postgres
```